# Spawn Inmemory server in Scala

Tags: scala, rest

I am writing a Scala script to test one of my Rest end point. In order to test it, I need to spawn another server and few endpoints on it. Till now I have hosted these end points in another service, but as these end pints are temporary and required only during execution of script, I want these end points should made available only during execution of script. Is it possible to spawn an in memory server from scala script.

Comment: In general yes. Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: Akka HTTP has several examples: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example